# Templated Iterator declaration

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I have to create a generic function that will work for vectors, linked lists and double linked lists. 
I want to use an iterator to parse through to find if val is in the vector, linked list or double linked list.
I just don't know how to declare a generic iterator. Below is my attempt at the declaration.

```
template <class Container, class T>
void findValue(Container &x, const T &val){
std::x<T>::iterator it;
}
```

Comment: One way would be to pass `std::list<Whatever>` as the container, and use `Container::iterator`.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `std::find`?

Comment: @PeteBecker Well the ultimate goal of this function is to see if val already exists, and if it does the function will insert val right next where it already exists. So if val is 3, { 2,4,3,5} will be {2,4,3,3,5}. And I don't think find will return the position.

Comment: [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns iterator

Comment: @Lin0523 Your problem description in the comment has nothing to do what was asked in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since C++ containers define the nested type `iterator`, you can use `typename Container::iterator` to declare an iterator in your `findValue` function (although `auto` will work just as well). There's also no need to take `T` as a separate template parameter because you can use `typename Container::value_type`.

```
template<typename Container>
void findValue(Container& x, const typename Container::value_type & val)
{
    // could use 'typename Container::iterator' instead of 'auto'
    for (auto it = begin(x); it != end(x); ++it)
    {
        if (*it == val)
        {
            std::cout << "found " << val << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```